# Finding the location for sumo for a Mac using the terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, directory, sumo

I'm trying to install SUMO on my Mac by following the steps in this link:

https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Installing/index.html#macos

Currently, I'm on the step:

```
export SUMO_HOME="/your/path/to/sumo"
```

I cleared my terminal without copying the directory it was saved to so I can replace */your/path/to/sumo*.

When attempting to find its directory, I run the following:

```
which sumo
```

and I get the output

```
/usr/local/bin/sumo
```

Which when I try to go to it returns that it is not a directory:

```
cd: not a directory: /usr/local/bin/sumo
```

**How can I find the path to sumo on my mac? or is this the right path and I'm missing something?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the path to the sumo executable but to the installation directory which is needed here, probably `/usr/local/share/sumo`. Maybe it helps to run `find / -name sumo | grep share`.

Comment: I got stuck in finding the actual path of SUMO in my MacBook. I wrote the command: find / -name sumo | grep share , like mentioned above, in terminal and it shows me find: /dev/fd/3: Not a directory
find: /dev/fd/4: Not a directory
find: /dev/fd/6: Not a directory
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sumo/1.11.0/share/sumo
/opt/homebrew/share/sumo.      and in .zsh I paste the following command: export SUMO_HOME=“/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sumo/1.11.0/share/sumo
/opt/homebrew/share/sumo" but after running echo $SUMO_HOME it doesn't show me anything. I appreciate of anyone's solution to this

Comment: You need to decide on one of the two, so just `export SUMO_HOME="/opt/homebrew/share/sumo"` should do the trick. Furthermore you need to relogin or at least open a new shell after you edited .zshrc or .bashrc or you reread it using the source command